# AWS Cognito triggers - Are they synchronous?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I couldn't find this in the docs, maybe I'm searching for the wrong words.

But for example, I have a lambda trigger on AWS Cognito to create an entry for the user in the DynamoDB table everytime a new user is created.

So, when the frontend uses Cognito API to create an user, and the request return sucessfully, how can I know my lambda trigger already ran and completed? How can I guarantee the user is already in the DynamoDB table?

Comment: They are synchronous. You could check the CloudWatch logs to find some evidence.